# New routing settings without network restart in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

After we added a new routing for an interface permanently, with ex.: nmtui, we usually do a:

```
systemctl restart network
```

but can we add the new routing without a full network restart?

Comment: `ip route` changes are usually executed with immediate effect.

Comment: we doesn't use the "ip" command, updated the question, thank you and sorry :)

Comment: You're going to have to use `ip` for immediate changes. The general idea is that a network service restart is for bootstrapping the system (or testing it) and you use `ip` to make changes that will be lost on boot. I would suggest you use `ip route` to change the routing settings right now and modify the persistent service configuration as appropriate for the next time the system boots.

Comment: but what if we mistype the permanent rules? :) aren't there any offical, more reliable way?